# How to get all the contents from a word file document and display it in a div using php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

```
$content = file_get_contents('filepath');
echo $content;
```

When a resume is uploaded I need to preview the resume as it is using PHP codeiginter.

Comment: did u implemented the same ?

Comment: Yes i implemented the same, but im getting data with encrypted form.. @ safin chacko

Comment: Why don't you use fopen();

Comment: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below function

```
function read_docx("filePath"){

    $striped_content = '';
    $content = '';

    if(!$filename || !file_exists($filename)) return false;

    $zip = zip_open($filename);
    if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip)) return false;

    while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {

        if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE) continue;

        if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml") continue;

        $content .= zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));

        zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
    }
    zip_close($zip);      
    $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', " ", $content);
    $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p>', "\r\n", $content);
    $striped_content = strip_tags($content);

    return $striped_content;
}
```